# Write to file with temporary buffer using ofstream

Tags: c++, iostream

How can I write a series of numbers (in binary) preceded by its length, without knowing the length beforehand?

Can I write the number series to a temporary buffer (e.g. `buf.write()`), determine the buffer length, and copy the buffer to an `ofstream` afterwards (e.g. `ofs << buf`)?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: 1. No. How can you write the length if you don't know it? 2. Yes.

Comment: 1. Write data to buffer - 2. Determine buffer length - 3. Write length to file - 4. Write data to file

Comment: Quite obviously the data I want to write is more complex than a couple of numbers written using a loop. Otherwise I could simply use a counter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are writing in binary mode to the file, reserve a location for the quantity.

For example, let's have an 32-bit value for the quantity.  We could write that at the beginning of the file:

```
uint32_t number_size = 0U;

// Open output file for read & write.
// Reserve space for the quantity by writing dummy value.
output_file.write((char *)&number_size, sizeof(number_size));

// Perform calculations & writing to file, incrementing "number_size"  

// Write the number size to the top of the file:
output_file.seekp(0, SEEK_BEG);
output_file.write((char *)&number_size, sizeof(number_size));
```

You can place quantity variable anywhere, just remember its file position. When finished, seek to that position and write it in.